# How to move cursor more than one line up?

Tags: python

I was searching around stack overflow and couldn't find an answer to my question. So as I take it there are are a variety of ways to edit a recently printed line of code; using the `end=''` or the `\033[F` and `\033[A` characters but none of them let me edit more than one line up in my code and only move the cursor up once. Is there a way to edit however many lines up I want like for example: `\033[F(lines=4)`?

As example code:

```
import time
print("Line 1")
time.sleep(1)
print("Line 2")
time.sleep(1)
print("Line 1 sequel")
```

How could I potentially overwrite the already printed `Line 1` with `Line 1 sequel`?

Comment: Probably *not* what you want, but you could use `print('line 1\nline 2')` to get it into one editable statement...?

Comment: But that's just printing down a line. I was wondering if there was a way to write `\033[F` multiple times to go up multiple times or something like that.